# How to know from which form this form got loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on jsps with javascript and jquery. 
I have a form(say DisplayListForm) which gets loaded from 2 different forms. One from FilterForm and another saveChangesForm. There are submit buttons on both forms. Now My question is, how can I know from which form DisplayListForm was targeted? Depending on from where is the request is coming I want to change the display.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have control over the FilterForm and saveChangesForm, I'd suggest putting a hidden form field in each of those:

```
<input type="hidden" name="origin" value="nameOfTheForm" />
```

Server side, you can detect the `origin` field and change your view accordingly.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Small, off-topic nitpick: I've found that using a consistent naming scheme can save some headaches, e.g. capitalizing both FilterForm and SaveChangesForm. :)

Answer (score 1):

Its really simple, Name all your submit buttons on the client side and then check for the submitted button on the server.

Example:

```
//Client-side
<form>
    <input type="submit" name="submit-button" value="add-item"/>
</form> 
<form>
    <input type="submit" name="submit-button" value="delete-item"/>
</form>

//Server-side
 if($_POST)
  {
        if($_POST['submit-button']=='add-item')
                      //add an item
         else
                      //delete an item                   
  }
```